# Understanding assumptions about machine word size in analyzing computer algorithms

Tags: algorithm, integer

I am reading the book [Introduction to Algorithms](http://highered.mcgraw-hill.com/sites/0070131511/) by  Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest, Clifford Stein.. In the second chapter under "Analyzing Algorithms" it is mentioned that :

> We also assume a limit on the size of each word of data. For example , when working with inputs of size n , we typically assume that integers are represented by c lg n bits for some constant c>=1 . We require c>=1 so that each word can hold the value of n , enabling us to index the individual input elements , and we restrict c to be a constant so that the word size doesn't grow arbitrarily .( If the word size could grow arbitrarily , we could store huge amounts of data in one word and operate on it all in constant time - clearly an unrealistic scenario.)

My questions are why this assumption that each integer should be represented by c lg n bits and also how c>=1 being the case allows us to index the individual input elements ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

first, by `lg` they apparently mean log base 2, so `lg n` is the number of bits in `n`.

then what they are saying is that if they have an algorithm that takes a list of numbers (i am being more specific in my example to help make it easier to understand) like `1,2,3,...n` then they assume that:

- a "word" in memory is big enough to hold any of those numbers.
- a "word" in memory is not big enough to hold *all* the numbers (in one single word, packed in somehow).
- when calculating the number of "steps" in an algorithm, an operation on one "word" takes one step.

the reason they are doing this is to keep the analysis realistic (you can only store numbers up to some size in "native" types; after that you need to switch to arbitrary precision libraries) without choosing a particular example (like 32 bit integers) that might be inappropriate in some cases, or become outdated.

Comment: n is the size of the input but also the last element in the input ? Is it me or it's not clear at all in the book ?

Answer (score 4):

You need at least lg n bits to represent integers of size n, so that's a lower bound on the number of bits needed to store inputs of size n.  Setting the constant c >= 1 makes it a lower bound.  If the constant multiplier were less than 1, you wouldn't have enough bits to store n.

This is a simplifying step in the RAM model.  It allows you to treat each individual input value as though it were accessible in a single slot (or "word") of memory, instead of worrying about complications that might arise otherwise.  (Loading, storing, and copying values of different word sizes would take differing amounts of time if we used a model that allowed varying word lengths.)  This is what's meant by "enabling us to index the individual input elements."  Each input element of the problem is assumed to be accessible at a single address, or index (meaning it fits in one word of memory), simplifying the model.

Comment: "You need at least lg n bits to represent integers of size n, so that's a lower bound on the number of bits needed to store inputs of size n." . Do you mean we need that many bits to store all the inputs or individual inputs ?

Comment: @BilltheLizard: the "size" of an integer is rather ambiguous :)

Comment: @larsmans but why are they making such an assumption we can have inputs like 123456, 2, 3456789, 234 . So here n=4 . can lg 4 bits hold 123456 ?

Comment: @larsmans I see . I was confused by the "inputs of size n" and interpreted it like a input sequence of size n

Comment: @Geek: wait a minute, I totally misread the quote. *n* actually is the size of the input. Cormen et al. are postulating that the size of integers is a function of the input size. You need large word sizes to handle large problems, but the word size must be capped somehow.

Comment: @Geek You need lg n bits to store an individual integer with the value of n.  The language in the book (and in a lot of other books) is a little bit tricky here because you have two different sizes you're concerned about when you say "the size of the input."  That could mean the number of elements in a list, or the size of each element.  Here it's just the size of one element.

Comment: This is part is very poorly written, I was also totally confused wondering what the number of elements in the input (n) has to do with the number of bits to store each individual value.. Plus he never defined what a word was. This is discouraging me from continuing reading the book

Answer (score 2):

This question was asked very long ago and the explanations really helped me, but I feel like there could still be a little more clarification about how the lg n came about. For me talking through things really helps:

Lets choose a random number in base 10, like 27, we need 5 bits to store this. Why? Well because 27 is 11011 in binary. Notice 11011 has 5 digits each 'digit' is what we call a bit hence 5 bits.

Think of each bit as being a slot. For binary, each of those slots can hold a 0 or 1. What's the largest number I can store with 5 bits? Well, the largest number would fill each slot: 11111

11111 = 31 = 2^5 so to store 31 we need 5 bits and 31 is 2^5

Generally (and I will use very explicit names for clarity):

numToStore = 2 ^ numBitsNeeded

Since log is the mathematical inverse of exponent we get:
log(numToStore) = numBitsNeeded

Since this is likely to not result in an integer, we use ceil to round our answer up. So applying our example to find how many bits are needed to store the number 31:

log(31) = 4.954196310386876 = 5 bits